# how to call Swift closure callback

Tags: swift, closures

I am trying to get service data in presenter and then invoking method from presenter using view reference in ViewController
ho can i get callback from service.
i have Service/Presenter/View
My Code is as follows

ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UserView {

    private var userPresenter: UserPresenter?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        userPresenter = UserPresenter(userView: self)
        userPresenter?.getUsers()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func startLoading() {
        print("Start loading is called")
    }

    func stopLoading() {
        print("Stop loading is called")
    }

    func onEmpty() {
        print("Empty users returned")
    }

    func onUsers(users: [User]) {
        for userItem in users {
            print("User name \(userItem.getName())")
        }
    }

}
```

View

```
protocol UserView: NSObjectProtocol {
    func startLoading()

    func stopLoading()

    func onUsers(users: [User])

    func onEmpty()
}
```

Service

```
public class UserService {

    func getUsers(delay: Double, completion: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {
        var users = [User]()


        users.append(User(name: "User 1", email:"user1@gmail.com", age: 25))
        users.append(User(name: "User 2", email: "user2@gmail.com", age: 26))
        users.append(User(name: "User 3", email: "user3@gmail.com", age: 27))

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
            print("Sending users")
            completion(users)
            print("Sent user")
        }
    }
}
```

Presenter

```
class UserPresenter {

    private var userService: UserService
    weak private var userView: UserView?

    init(userView: UserView) {
        self.userView = userView
        userService = UserService()
    }

    func detachView() {
        self.userView = nil
    }

    func getUsers() {
        self.userView?.startLoading()
        userService.getUsers(delay: 5000, completion: {
            users: [User] -> Void
                print("adad")
        })

}
```

How should i get the callback method when async task finishes

```
func getUsers() {
    self.userView?.startLoading()

    userService.getUsers(delay: 5000){ users in

        print("\(users.count) users added")

        //            self.userView?.onUsers(users: users)
        //            self.userView?.stopLoading()

    }
}
```

This is not working as given in answer by @vadian

Comment: delay 5000 means 5000 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function is supposed to be called

```
func getUsers() {
    self.userView?.startLoading()
    userService.getUsers(delay: 5000) { users in
        print("\(users.count) users added")
    }
}
```

With *trailing closure* syntax the `completion` parameter name can be omitted. The `in` keyword after the return parameter is mandatory.

Comment: i am only getting Start loading is called in logs nothing after that?

Comment: Sending Users and Sent users logs are not getting printed?

Comment: As mentioned in the question comment 5000 are seconds. So you have to wait almost 2 hours ;-)

Comment: it is seconds in java it is miliseconds :'(

Comment: This is not java. You can pass seconds, milliseconds and nanoseconds using appropriate initializers. Seconds is the default.